# How to get more than 96 vCPU with gcloud

Tags: gcloud

I've just learned that the max vCPU one can use per region with gcloud is 96.  At the same time, I'm pretty sure you can build a managed instance group composed of 2200 computers.  I would think this managed instance group would be more than 96.  Suppose I want to use more than 96 vCPU.  What would be the best way to do it if it's possible?  Should I just build another 96 vCPU in another region or perhaps use managed instance groups?

Comment: Get one of the m1- or m2-ultramem boxes :-)

Comment: Why would that help?

Comment: Those boxes have hundreds of vCPU, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the max for N type machines is 96 vCPUs. You would need to create in multiple regions if you needed to.

However, in the documentation [Machine Types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types), there are the types of M1 and M2 machine types, that support more than that - M2 for example, support 208 or 416 vCPUs. I would recommend you take a look at this above documentation, to confirm if this would help you. :)

Let me know if the information helped you!